# If I set the value to find as a variable, why doesn't it work?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, find

When calling the findProd function with the number 1, everything works correctly. However, if I replace the number 1 with the idToFind variable, the console outputs undefined. Why is this happening?

P.S. in my file, if I print idToFind, the result is 1.

```
addToCartButtons.forEach(button => {

    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        const idToFind = event.target.dataset.id;

        let array = [{id: 1, name: 'mattia'}, {id: 2, name: 'cesare'}];

        function findProd(product) {
            return product.id === 1;
        }

        const result = array.find(findProd);
        console.log(result);

    })
});
```

I need to make the comparison value of the function dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `event.target.dataset.id` is a string. The strict comparison operator you use compares types first, so `1 === '1'` results in `false`.

Notice how you can convert string value to a number value with an unary `+`. Then `1 === 1` would result in `true` and in consequence, your `find` function will work as expected.

```
addToCartButtons.forEach(button => {

    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        const idToFind = event.target.dataset.id;

        let array = [{id: 1, name: 'mattia'}, {id: 2, name: 'cesare'}];

        function findProd(product) {
            return product.id === +idToFind;
        }

        const result = array.find(findProd);
        console.log(result);

    })
});
```

Also, the code would benefit in readability from using an array function and converting the identifier to number during the variablie initialization.

```
addToCartButtons.forEach(button => {

    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        const idToFind = +event.target.dataset.id;

        let array = [{id: 1, name: 'mattia'}, {id: 2, name: 'cesare'}];

        const result = array.find((product) => product.id === idToFind);
        console.log(result);

    })
});
```

You may want to read more about the [strict equality `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality).